# Do I need to enroll in apple developer program to use push notification service

Tags: android, ios, xcode, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications

I am developing the Iconic hybrid IOS app and confused on push notification service.

Do I need to enroll in apple developer program to use push notification service or is there any other solutions for it?

Thanks

Comment: If you are planing to submit the appstore you need to enroll in the program - the features you use do not matter. Or are you talking about using apns in the testing environment without an enrollment?

Comment: Yes, and after that will i need a account to upload the app on apple store.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you must enroll in Apple's developer program. To quote their site:

> APNs is available to apps distributed through the iOS App Store, tvOS
>   App Store, and Mac App Store, as well as to enterprise apps. Your app
>   must be provisioned and code signed to use APNs.

In order to submit apps to the app store, or sign them as enterprise apps you have to be enrolled in the developer program.

I don't think you can even test push notifications unless you're enrolled.

Comment: Thanks for answer ,but if i enroll in developer programme then to upload a app on store will need another charges or will be cover with same developer account

Comment: If you want to do installs from your server you'll need an Enterprise account, which is for companies to deliver apps to their employees. (Other uses are prohibited.) I believe an enterprise account is $200.00/year, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Sir, @DuncanC

until now we still need it right?

Comment: @Eliot, it isn't clear what you are asking. If you want to submit apps to the app store, you will need a paid developer account, and that is likely always going to be true. There are not other charges to upload an app to the store (other than Apple taking 30% of your sales.)

Answer (score 0):

How about just local push notifications?